# routerLink not compiling with TS template syntax

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I have a component like this http://plnkr.co/edit/mJDHZIm5IzeMB9f2IVLE:

```
@Component({
  template: `
      <p [innerHTML]="link"></p>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/two', component: Two, name: 'Two'},
])
export class App {
  two = (text: string) => `<a [routerLink]="['/Two']">${text}</a>`;
  constructor(private _router: Router) {  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.link = `${this.two("two")}`;
  }
}
```

Any ideas why it's not compiling `link` value or how to make it work? The goal is to hardcode url, and just change text of the generated link.

#### UPDATE:

I also tried:

```
two = (text: string) => `<a href="/two">${text}</a>`;
```

which works in plunker with `#/two` because of HashLocationStrategy, but in my app router isn't detecting the link and whole page reloads...

Answer (score 1):

`routerLink` is a directive. Directives and components are not created for HTML added with `innerHTML`.

If you make `link` an `Array` instead of a `string`.

This should work

```
<p [routerLink]="link"></p>
```

```
this.link = ['Two'];
```

Comment: I'm trying to hardcode link/hef, and just change text value/label.

Comment: Why not just bind the label text and `href` instead of the entire link? If you want it to add dynamically you'd need to use `DynamicComponentLoader`

Comment: Because it needs to go into another component (generic notification), I just simplified example alot (;

Comment: The options are currently quite limited. Either you don't get any binding or directives or you use DCL.